# Find bound on order of Bessel function

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions

I need to evaluate and store the first *significant* ($n$) orders for a given abscissa for the [Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). That is, $J_v(x), \ v \in [0, n]$.  Here *significant* means that I want to find a small-ish $n$ such that $J_v(x) < \epsilon, \forall \ v \ge n$.

Empirically the evaluations seem to be approximately sinusoidal and increasing in amplitude until around $v \ge x$ where it starts to clamp down towards $0$.  So $n$ is at least as large as $x$, but not much larger.

For instance here's the Matlab graph for the first 100 orders evaluated at 50.  That is, $J_v(50), \ 0 \le v \le 100$.

```
plot(0:100, besslej(0:100, 50))
```

[image: plot(0:100, besslej(0:100, 50))]

In the graph, $n \approx 60$. Is there any guidance for finding my $n$ in the general case?

Empirically it seems to be about $n \approx |x|+3.4 + \Large{\frac{-\log_{10}\epsilon}{1.4}}|x|^\frac{1}{3}$, at least for $x > 1$

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking for.  You're saying you have some fixed $x$, and you want some range for $v$, I think?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  All the resources I'm finding talk about it the other way around.

Comment: Could you clarify which range for $v$ you want?

Comment: In the graph after around $n=60$ the function is basically $0$ from then on, so for this case $n$ is around 60.  Then I'd want to calculate all the $J_v(x)$ for $v$ between $0$ and $60$.